# Convert linq result to name value pair

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query that returns multiply rows.  The first row is the name and the second row is the actual value.  The end result is to take a specific name and add the value to a datatable row.

Code:

```
    var query = from table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@border='0']")
                from row in table.SelectNodes("tr")
                from cell in row.SelectNodes("th|td")
                where (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.InnerText.ToString()))
                && cell.InnerText.ToString() != "File Summary"
                && cell.InnerText.ToString() != "Payment Instructions"
                && cell.InnerText.ToString() != "Number"
                select cell.InnerText;

    foreach (var cell in query)
    {
        logger.Info("{0}", cell);
    }
```

Result

```
2020-03-18 15:29:04.5074 INFO Client Name:
2020-03-18 15:29:04.5764 INFO Siemens
2020-03-18 15:29:04.5764 INFO Client ID:
2020-03-18 15:29:04.5764 INFO 7000002
2020-03-18 15:29:04.5764 INFO Batch File Name:
2020-03-18 15:29:04.5764 INFO 6030001030-20200303-00005470
2020-03-18 15:29:04.5764 INFO File Status:
2020-03-18 15:29:04.5764 INFO Successful
2020-03-18 15:29:04.5764 INFO Sent
2020-03-18 15:29:04.5764 INFO 7
2020-03-18 15:29:04.5764 INFO Batch File ID:
2020-03-18 15:29:04.5764 INFO 0008615020
2020-03-18 15:29:04.5764 INFO Date Uploaded:
2020-03-18 15:29:04.5764 INFO 03-Mar-2020
2020-03-18 15:29:04.5764 INFO Successful
2020-03-18 15:29:04.5764 INFO 7
2020-03-18 15:29:04.5764 INFO Creator:
2020-03-18 15:29:04.5884 INFO STP-SIEMENSCORPOR
2020-03-18 15:29:04.5884 INFO Failed
2020-03-18 15:29:04.5884 INFO 0
```

Eventually

```
string clientname = value[x]; or something similar
```

Tried:

```
    var data = query.ToList();
    var obj = data.Select((item, index) =>
    {
        if (index < data.Count - 1 && index % 2 == 0)
            return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(item, data[index + 1]);
        return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(null, null);
    }).Where(x => x.Key != null);
```

But obj is null for the KeyValuePair

Comment: what you meant by clientname = value[x]???

Comment: `select new KeyValuePair<string,string>(..., ...)` work?

Comment: I need to convert the even row values to individual strings to use as column values in a data table.  For example dt.column.add("clientname") then set that value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
List<string> data = new List<string>() { "Client Name", "Siemens", "Client ID", "7000002", "File Status", "Successful" };

var obj = data.Select((item, index) =>
 {
     if (index < data.Count - 1 && index % 2 == 0)
         return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(item, data[index + 1]);
     return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(null, null);
 }).Where(x => x.Key != null);
```

In place of data in above code, you can use your variable: query

This is overtly confusing, so a simpler way is:

```
Dictionary<string, string> map = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for (int idx = 0; idx < data.Count - 1; idx += 2)
{
    map[data[idx]] = data[idx + 1];
}
```

Comment: Looking at the obj variable its null for both key and value.

Comment: Yes those are the cases we dont want. The Select will run for each index in the List. We want the dictionary where item at 0 is key and 1 is value, 2 is key and 3 is value. So the null null item represents the cases where Odd index tries to be key. You can replace this with a simple for loop too.

Comment: This solution does not work.  Not all properties are 2 line.

Comment: @jdweng - It works if you have even or odd - what ever number of items. You are solving wrong problem. Note that OP doesnt want logger.Info output t be parsed.

Answer (score 1):

You need random access, so your first step should be to realize the results and store them in memory.

```
var list = query.ToList();
```

Once you have that you can access via index and assemble the rows you need.

```
var dictionary = Enumerable.Range(0, list.Count / 2)
    .ToDictionary
    (
        i => list[i * 2],
        i => list[i * 2 + 1]
    );
```

Comment: Thats Good one - :)

Comment: This solution does not work. Not all properties are 2 line.

Comment: You are mistaken @jdweng

Comment: Look at my results. He is parsing text. Doesn't this make a lot more sense than the other solutions : Key : Date Uploaded, Value : 03-Mar-2020,Successful,7

Answer (score 0):

I've been parsing text files for over 45 years.  The code below works when each item contains 2 or more rows.  Not like the other solution.  Using mod 2 will not work in this case (or divided by 2)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.txt";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string line = "";
            Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            string buffer = "";
            string key = "";
            Boolean first = true;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                if (line.Length > 0)
                {
                    string[] splitLine = line.Split(new string[] { "INFO" }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToArray();
                    if (splitLine[1].Contains(":"))
                    {
                        if (!first)
                        {
                            dict.Add(key, buffer);

                        }
                        key = splitLine[1].Trim(new char[] { ' ', ':' });
                        buffer = "";
                        first = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (buffer == string.Empty)
                        {
                            buffer = splitLine[1].Trim();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            buffer += "," + splitLine[1].Trim();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            dict.Add(key, buffer);
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in dict)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Key '{0}' : Value '{1}'", pair.Key, pair.Value);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Well you got the question wrong, the lines under Result section with Time stamp and INFo and text message is the output coz OP is using a logging framework "Note: logger.Info("{0}", cell);". So you are solving wrong problem. He is parsing an HTML source and creating that query variable. Which he wants to be converted to Dictionary.

Comment: Look at my results.  He is parsing text.  Doesn't this make a lot more sense than the other solutions : Key : Date Uploaded, Value : 03-Mar-2020,Successful,7

Comment: :( You need to read the question again may be. The Text you are trying to Parse is the output of OP's loop where is says Logger.Info - which is Log4Net or similar framework writing log message. The question he has is even before code reaches this loop. If you get it this time great, if you dont. Wait until OP (who has found his solution already) comes back to thank you.

Comment: I think it's clear from the question that the input for this conversion is not the log text, but `query`.  So, while this answer isn't wrong, it's probably making things harder than it needs to.  Although, I think some of the confusion stems from the fact that some of the name rows don't end with a semicolon.  Thus, are there two pairs, `File Status=Successful` and `Sent=7`?  Or one pair, `File Status=Successful,Sent,7`?  Other than talking about "first" and "second" (so, presumably, alternating) rows, the question doesn't say, so this interpretation isn't unreasonable in that regard.

Comment: I've parsed 1000 of text files over the years.  So when a OP post a parsing problem I'm I use my experience and do not necessarily to exactly what the OP requests.  I do what makes the most sense based on the input data and past experience.

Answer (score 0):

Since all you ever need is consecutive `string`s - not the entire collection - to produce a [pair](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2), you can manually enumerate your query two at a time using an [iterator method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/iterators#enumeration-sources-with-iterator-methods) to [`yield`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield) results as soon as they are available...

```cs
static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ExtractPairsByEnumeration(IEnumerable<string> items)
{
    using (var itemEnumerator = items.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (itemEnumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            string name = itemEnumerator.Current;

            if (!itemEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                // We received a name item with no following value item
                // Use whatever default value you want here
                yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(name, "<none>");
                yield break;
            }
            else
                yield return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(name, itemEnumerator.Current);
        }
    }
}
```

You would call it like this...

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SO60748447
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string InputText = @"
Client Name:
Siemens
Client ID:
7000002
Batch File Name:
6030001030-20200303-00005470
File Status:
Successful
Sent
7
Batch File ID:
0008615020
Date Uploaded:
03-Mar-2020
Successful
7
Creator:
STP-SIEMENSCORPOR
Failed
0";

        static void Main()
        {
            string[] inputLines = InputText.Trim().Split("\r\n");
            IEnumerable<string>[] testQueries = new IEnumerable<string>[] {
                inputLines,
                inputLines.Take(inputLines.Length - 1)
            };

            foreach (IEnumerable<string> query in testQueries)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Extracting {query.Count()} input lines:");
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in ExtractPairsByEnumeration(query))
                    Console.WriteLine($"\t{pair}");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...which produces output like this...

```
Extracting 20 input lines:
    [Client Name:, Siemens]
    [Client ID:, 7000002]
    [Batch File Name:, 6030001030-20200303-00005470]
    [File Status:, Successful]
    [Sent, 7]
    [Batch File ID:, 0008615020]
    [Date Uploaded:, 03-Mar-2020]
    [Successful, 7]
    [Creator:, STP-SIEMENSCORPOR]
    [Failed, 0]

Extracting 19 input lines:
    [Client Name:, Siemens]
    [Client ID:, 7000002]
    [Batch File Name:, 6030001030-20200303-00005470]
    [File Status:, Successful]
    [Sent, 7]
    [Batch File ID:, 0008615020]
    [Date Uploaded:, 03-Mar-2020]
    [Successful, 7]
    [Creator:, STP-SIEMENSCORPOR]
    [Failed, <none>]
```

Notice that it still produces reasonable output in the second case when given an odd number of lines.

A LINQ alternative that also requires only an `IEnumerable<>` is to use the [`Aggregate()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate).  This takes a delegate to which is passed each item in the input sequence and an accumulator (i.e. `list`) that you use to store the results to that point...

```cs
static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ExtractPairsByAggregation(IEnumerable<string> items)
{
    return items
        // Aggregate() doesn't have an overload that provides the index,
        // so package it together with each item in a ValueTuple using Select()
        .Select((item, index) => (item, index))
        .Aggregate(
            // Storage for both intermediate and final results
            new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(),
            (list, current) => {
                if (current.index % 2 == 0) // Even items are a name
                {
                    KeyValuePair<string, string> newPair = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
                        current.item, "<none>"
                    );

                    // Add a partial pair as soon as it's encountered
                    // so it's still present in the results even if
                    // this is the last item in the sequence
                    list.Add(newPair);
                }
                else                        //  Odd items are a value
                {
                    // The last pair in the list is the corresponding partial pair
                    int pairIndex = list.Count - 1;
                    KeyValuePair<string, string> oldPair = list[pairIndex];
                    // KeyValuePair<> is immutable, so recreate it now that we have the value
                    KeyValuePair<string, string> newPair = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
                        oldPair.Key, current.item
                    );

                    list[pairIndex] = newPair;
                }

                // Return the same list so it is available for the
                // next item in the sequence and as the final result
                return list;
            }
        );
}
```

Unlike `ExtractPairsByEnumeration()`, this returns the full results when they're all available, instead of one at a time.  If you call this in the `Main()` method above the output is the same.

By the way, assuming these are classes from the HTML Agility Pack you're using then calling `cell.InnerText.ToString()` is unnecessary because `InnerText` is, as the name implies, already a `string`, but if you insist on calling it you should use a [`let` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/let-clause) so you can call it once and reuse the result...

```cs
[snip]
from cell in row.SelectNodes("th|td")
let cellText = cell.InnerText.ToString()
where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cellText)
    && cellText != "File Summary"
    && cellText != "Payment Instructions"
    && cellText != "Number"
    select cell.InnerText;// This should probably be cellText as well
```